# Can I make html tags work based on screen sizes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was looking at some of my code in Safari when I resized the page and it didn't look great. I need to restyle it, and using the media tag I added another style sheet. It looks better now but there are still some aspects of the page that don't look good that I could easily fix with html. When I add the html, the page starts to look better but then when I make the browser full page is look weird. Is there a way to make an html tag work based on the screen size? I am looking for something like the "media" tag used when linking a style sheet. I also have JavaScript and jQuery on my site if that helps, but that's it.

Comment: To clarify: Do you want to serve different HTML, based on client screen-size?

Comment: I think you're looking for "responsive" web design. Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp There are many responsive frameworks. See http://www.awwwards.com/what-are-frameworks-22-best-responsive-css-frameworks-for-web-design.html as a starting point.

Comment: Have you looked at [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)?

Comment: you've lost the plot about responsive design entirely, go back and start from square 1 otherwise what you're trying to do will lead you to usless duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this

```
 @media
```

example this will only on width of 500px or higher

```
@media (min-width:500px)
{
    /*Class name*/
    {
      /*properties*/
    }
}
```

similarly you can specify max width but to save time you should use popular framework [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) compatible with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

if you want that html tag work based on the screen size then you need to work on responsive css or you can you any framework like bootstrap or foundation many more available for html and css where u can get visibilities classes for you html